# Scala read file and split and modify each line

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I'm new to Scala. I want to read lines from a text file and split and make changes to each lines and output them.

Here is what I got:

```
 val pre:String = " <value enum=\""
 val mid:String = "\" description=\""
 val sur:String = "\"/>"

 for(line<-Source.fromFile("files/ChargeNames").getLines){
    var array = line.split("\"")
    println(pre+array(1)+mid+array(3)+sur);
 }
```

It works but in a Object-Oriented programming way rather than a Functional programming way.

I want to get familiar with Scala so anyone who could change my codes in Functional programming way?

Thx.

Comment: I'd say it is already in functional style, when ignoring the side-effects of printing the result (and maybe not closing the `Source`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One traversal and no additional memory

```
 Source
  .fromFile("files/ChargeNames")
  .getLines
  .map { line =>
    //do stuff with line like
    line.replace('a', 'b')
  }
  .foreach(println)
```

Or code which is a little bit faster, [according to @ziggystar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035252/scala-read-file-and-split-and-modify-each-line#comment31630350_21035302)

```
Source
  .fromFile("files/ChargeNames")
  .getLines
  .foreach { line =>
    //do stuff with line like
    println(line.replace('a', 'b'))
  }
```

Comment: Actually, this solution is not better than original. It requires additional memory and makes two traversal instead of one. And in "real world" you should close `Source` after using.

Comment: Hi, where's the "additional memory" and "two traversal"? Would you please share a better solution?

Comment: The question was about functional way, not about performance. Solution provides functional way, not imperative

Comment: I have update answer for lower memory usage and one traversal

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko You know that `getLines` returns an `Iterator[String]`? There is one traversal in both cases. So the answer doesn't make much sense (the comment and the second code block). Though the second block is more performant for other reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about iterator :(

Comment: So how do you save the changes made to a new file?

Answer (score 5):

```
val ans = for (line <- Source.fromFile.getLines) yield (line.replace('a', 'b')
ans foreach println
```